# Json nested array send to php file returns null

Tags: php, arrays, json, nested

```
$locs='"[{"locid":"101","rows":[{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]"';
$locsArray = json_decode($locs, true);
echo json_encode($locsArray);

//output is : null
```

Comment: Because you don't need `'"`, only `'`

Comment: There is an extra `"` on the beginning and the end of the string.

Comment: Your JSON is invalid, you can use this : http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-last-error.php

Comment: $locs='[{"locid":"101","rows":[{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]';

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying, since I did have to go and sort through the mess you call CODE dude, you seriously have to check how many open and closed curly brackets there are.
But for your code here's the solution:

```
$locs = array("loicd"=>"101","rows"=>[array("itemcode"=>"100005","qty"=>10,"desc"=>"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs"=>"101"),array("itemcode"=>"100002","qty"=>20,"desc"=>"mango","locs"=>"101")]);
$js_en = json_encode($locs);
$js_dc = json_decode($js_en, true);
var_dump($js_dc);
print "<br />".$js_dc['rows'][0]['itemcode'];
```

Using var_dump() can really help when working with json_arrays

So instead of encoding a string you encode and array :)

Comment: $locksArray["locid"]; this is fine now, but echo $rows[0]["itemcode"];  here is the issue now Warning: Illegal string offset 'itemcode' in saveTransfer.php on line 78

Comment: figured it out, after going through the mess

Comment: @AnwarHassan Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update two things. first update `$locs`
change:

```
$locs='"[{"locid":"101","rows":
  [{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]"';
```

to:

```
$locs='[{"locid":"101","rows":
  [{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]';
```

then instead of `echo` use `print` and inside `forEach` you are trying iterate through `$locs` which is not **PHP Array** so instead you need to iterate through your parsed result which is `$locsArray`.

```
<?php
  $locs='[{"locid":"101","rows":
  [{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]';
  $locsArray = json_decode($locs, true);
  foreach($locsArray[0]["rows"] as $locRow) {
     echo $locRow["itemcode"];
  }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After your update where your new `$locs` variable is without the double quotes at the beginning and the end:

```
$locs='[{"locid":"101","rows":[{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]';
```

To get the "itemcode" you could update your foreach to:

```
$locs='[{"locid":"101","rows":[{"itemcode":"100005","qty":10,"desc":"Potato Chips Banana Chips","locs":"101"},{"itemcode":"100002","qty":20,"desc":"mango","locs":"101"}]}]';
$locsArray = json_decode($locs, true);
foreach($locsArray[0]["rows"] as $locs) {
    echo $locs["itemcode"];
}
```

That would give you `100005` and `100002`

To update your attempt for multiple results you could use:

```
foreach ($locsArray as $locs) {
    echo $locs["locid"];
    foreach ($locs["rows"] as $row) {
        echo $row["itemcode"];
    }
}
```

[See the Demo](https://3v4l.org/F6Lfa)